# Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME must be set or hadoop must be in the path

Tags: hadoop, installation, hive

So a little background. I've been trying to setup Hive on a CentOS 6 machine. I followed the instructions of this Youtube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2lSrHsRpOI

For my case, I'm using Hadoop-1.1.2 and Hive 0.9.0, all the directories labeled "mnt" in this video I replaced it with "opt" because that's where all of my hadoop and hive packages have been opened up.

As I reached the portion of the video where I was actually supposed to run Hive via "./hive"
this error popped up:

```
"Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME must be set or hadoop must be in the path"
```

I guess one of the questions I have is, in which directory did I have to edit the ".profile" file? because I don't understand why we would have to go to the "home" directory for this change. And also if this helps, this is what I had put down in the ".profile" file in my /home/hadoop directory

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop/hadoop
export HIVE_HOME=/opt/hadoop/hive
export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HIVE_HOME/bin
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Go to /etc/profile.d directory and create a hadoop.sh file in there with

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop/hadoop
export HIVE_HOME=/opt/hadoop/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HIVE_HOME/bin
```

After you save the file, make sure to

```
chmod +x /etc/profile.d/hadoop.sh
source /etc/profile.d/hadoop.sh
```

This should take care of it.