# Error in launching Spark REPL

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I got pre-built Spark 1.4.1 and I'm running HDP 2.6. when I try to run `spark-shell` it gives me an error message as follows.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments$$anonfun$mergeDefaultSparkProperties$1.apply(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments$$anonfun$mergeDefaultSparkProperties$1.apply(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:111)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.mergeDefaultSparkProperties(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 4):

> `ClassNotFoundException` occurs when class loader could not find the
>   required class in class path . So , basically you should check your
>   class path and add the class in the classpath.

Check whether `hadoop-common-0.21.0.jar` is added to your classpath.

Comment: where exactly I should add hadoop-commons.jar?

Comment: Do you have any spark-*.cmd file ?

Comment: I added the SPARK_CLASSPATH to the env variable and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your Hadoop home is not set, as in here?

[Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME must be set or hadoop must be in the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688466/cannot-find-hadoop-installation-hadoop-home-must-be-set-or-hadoop-must-be-in-t)